An old movie where people could load their minds into computers
There is an old movie which I rated as "my favorite" when I was a little kid but I can't remember its name now. It is about people with machines capable of uploading their mind into the internet/computers and live there. I also remember something about a bad group of people trying to take over the world for some reason. I have a vague image that the movie ended with the protagonist getting asked for help from the future or something.
Edit: The world that they planned to take over were both I think (real and virtual) as their plan were to completely move the civilization to the virtual world. I'm 25 from Chile but the movie was subtitled and in English. The upload was permanent but they could get downloaded again back to the real world.

How old, language or what country, was the upload permanent,  bad guys taking over which world?

Not much to go on but it sounds kind of like Lawnmover Man 2 from 1996. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116839/?ref_=tt_rec_tt - Jobe, having become a self aware A.I takes a shot a world domination by tempting people to upload into his virtual world. Let me know if it's correct and I'll post an answer you can accept.

@Dannie you should just answer it

@cde I dont know, seems kinda shaky. If OP doesn't reply I might just flag for lack of details. Is this type of comment frowned upon though?

Any recollection of "Casablanca" references or monkeys? There are elements in your question that match "Overdrawn at the Memory Bank," but that movie is so bonkers that you would likely remember more of the strangeness.

Could it be Brainstorm from 1983. People were able to record their thoughts and feeling, and play them back. Other people could also play them.


I don't remember anything about the future, but

there was a death, and what happens after(?), recorded that many people were after.

The trailer can be found here.

Thanks but it is not this one, although it looks interesting. Worth a try.

Maybe "The Thirteenth Floor" (1999). Scientists are uploading them selves to experimental virtual reality set in 1937.
Trailer:



IMDB:
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0139809/reference
There is some similarity to "The Matrix" but this is much different movie. I guess you know what is "The Matrix" or that is movie you are searching for?
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=The+Matrix+%281999%29
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0133093/reference

Can you please add to your answer to explain how this film fits the description in the question?
